# Maximo see response from publish channel json request

Tags: maximo

I have a publish channel for which I've added a Json Mapping in order to send Json Format to the endpoint defined. The issue I'm facing is that when the response message is an error I cannot see the response body that contains the reason of the error. Anyone has any idea on how I can see the error description that can be found in the response body ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this related to Maximo ***Spatial***? Sorry, I don't think I can help. Just wondering about the context.

Comment: @User1973 no.. it's not